# Why `as.factor` does not work when applied via `apply` function in R?

Tags: r, apply, r-factor

I wonder why `as.factor` function does not work when applied via `apply` function in `R`?

```
> df.nrow <- 10
> df <- data.frame(col1=sample(c("a","b","c"), df.nrow, TRUE),
+                  col2=sample(c("d","e","f"), df.nrow, TRUE),
+                  col3=sample(c("g","h","i"), df.nrow, TRUE))
> apply(df, 2, is.factor)
 col1  col2  col3 
FALSE FALSE FALSE 
> df <- apply(df, 2, as.factor)
> apply(df, 2, is.factor)
 col1  col2  col3 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: @isomorphismes - Please stop adding tags unless you add a tag description to [as.factor].  Right now it means nothing and helps no one.

Comment: @RichardScriven I added one already. It may not have been approved yet though.

Comment: @isomorphismes Don't add tags for arbitrary functions. That way lies madness. If the question is _fundamentally_ about factors, you might consider adding the already existing r-factor tag.

Comment: @joran Ah, ok, did not see the `r-factor` tag. That covers it.

Comment: @isomorphismes Tags are an unholy mess. The "right" tag is often very hard to find. It's generally better to avoid "guessing" at a new tag. Specifying a language/package/library is really all you need to worry about with tags. A good title will do more to help people find your question anyway.

Comment: @joran RichardScriven We can hop in a chat room if that's more appropriate...

Comment: @joran I think (and apparently so did someone else) that factors in R present enough of a challenge that they deserve a tag. Soooooo much overlap.

Comment: @isomorphismes We can discuss [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) although I need to run soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is because of how `apply` simplifies the result to return a matrix. From `?apply`:

```
If ‘X’ is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null
    ‘dim’ value (such as a data frame), ‘apply’ attempts to coerce it
    to an array via ‘as.matrix’ if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data
    frame) or via ‘as.array’.
```

In fact your original data frame is as you wish. Try `str(df)` or `sapply(df, is.factor)` to verify it. Basically character vectors are always coerced to factors, unless `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

Comment: I am afraid it does not work (just have checked it out).

Comment: If is your way of checking for factors that doesn't work. You can use `sapply(df, is.factor)`

Comment: Damn, you are right! :) I really apologize for my being careless!

Comment: Yeah basically `apply` coerces `df` to a matrix and then checks if its columns are factors, which they are not.. kind of tricky. I guess this is a good example why `lapply` should be used on data frames rather than `apply`.